# Find the elements with different values in two different array objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to find elements with different values in two different arrays like this?

**First Array**

```
[Object { id_request="009",  comment_bapak="First Comment"}, 
 Object { id_request="010",  comment_bapak="Second Comment"}, 
 Object { id_request="012",  comment_bapak=null}
]
```

**Second Array**

```
[Object { id_request="009",  comment_bapak="First Comment"}, 
 Object { id_request="010",  comment_bapak="Second Comment"}, 
 Object { id_request="012",  comment_bapak="New comment here ..... "}
]
```

I'll alert the element and its value. Example `id_request` "003"  `New comment here .....`

Comment: What output you expecting? where it is id_request "003" ?

Comment: I will create an alert, that "New comment on request 003" by js

Answer (score 2):

filter method approch [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4omaob6y/1/)

```
var diffItems = function (firstAr, secAr) {
    return firstAr.filter(function (fArItm) {
        return secAr.filter(function (sArItm) {
            return fArItm.comment_bapak === sArItm.comment_bapak;
        }).length === 0;
    });
};

var arr2 = [{
    id_request: "009",
    comment_bapak: "First Comment"
}, {
    id_request: "010",
    comment_bapak: "Second Comment"
}, {
    id_request: "012",
    comment_bapak: null
}];

var arr1 = [{
    id_request: "009",
    comment_bapak: "First Comment"
}, {
    id_request: "010",
    comment_bapak: "Second Comment"
}, {
    id_request: "012",
    comment_bapak: "New comment here ..... "
}];

console.log(diffItems(arr1, arr2)[0]['comment_bapak']);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's always goog to reduce the time Complexity.

If the `id` and target `attr` is fixed(in your case, which is `id_request` and `comment_bapak`), you can just use an object to convert first list to `map`.

Then for each item in second list, you just need to use the map the to get the related item in first list, then compare them.

The time Complexity would become `O(m + n)` instead of `O(m * n)`.

```js
var first = [{ id_request:"009",  comment_bapak:"First Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"010",  comment_bapak:"Second Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"012",  comment_bapak:null}
];

var second = [{ id_request:"009",  comment_bapak:"First Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"010",  comment_bapak:"Second Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"012",  comment_bapak:"New comment here ..... "}
];

var difference = function(list1, list2, id, attr) {
  var map = {};
  
  // Create map.
  list1.forEach(function(item) {
    map[item[id]] = item;
  });
  
  // Find diff.
  return list2.filter(function(item) {
    var target = map[item[id]];
    // Return if the item is not exist in first, or the target attr is different.
    return (typeof target === 'undefined' || item[attr] !== target[attr]);
  });
}

var diffs = difference(first, second, 'id_request', 'comment_bapak');
console.log(diffs);
console.log(diffs[0].comment_bapak);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the difference of two arrays by performing a nested `filter`, returning only the items of item a that are not contained within item b. For instance:

```js
var first = [{ id_request:"009",  comment_bapak:"First Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"010",  comment_bapak:"Second Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"012",  comment_bapak:null}
];

var second = [{ id_request:"009",  comment_bapak:"First Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"010",  comment_bapak:"Second Comment"}, 
 { id_request:"012",  comment_bapak:"New comment here ..... "}
];

// returns an array containing the unique objects
var difference = function(arr1, arr2) {
   return arr2.filter(function(item) {
     // filter all the matches and return the negation (0 matches = true = keep in array)
     return !arr1.filter(function(firstItem) {
        // compare comment_bapak
        return firstItem.comment_bapak == item.comment_bapak;
     }).length;
   });
 };

var differentItems = difference(first, second);

alert(differentItems[0].comment_bapak);
```