# Passing json result to another ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the continue from this : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132481/find-the-elements-with-different-values-in-two-different-array-objects-in-javasc)

My storyboard is like this. I want to autorefresh my page. Coz I create a live monitoring to manage requests from my users. When a new comment is create from user, I wanna create a notification.
So, I choose use js/jquery.

I try so hard to implement that to my ajax response like this

```
/* This is function to initialized old comment as return a first */
function initializedFirstComment(handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/getKomentarMD/' ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            handleData(data);
        }
    });

}
```

For the second array is like this :

```
/*For the second array */
    function refreshByManager(first) {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('notif-md');
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/getKomentarMD/' ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(second) {
                console.log(first); // For debug first array, and in firebug it success.
                console.log(second);// For debug second array, and in firebug it success.


                var difference = function(list1, list2, id, attr) {
                    var map = {};

                    // Create map.
                    list1.forEach(function(item) {
                        map[item[id]] = item;
                    });

                    // Find diff.
                    return list2.filter(function(item) {
                        var target = map[item[id]];
                        // Return if the item is not exist in first, or the target attr is different.
                        return (typeof target === 'undefined' || item[attr] !== target[attr]);
                    });
                }

                var diffs = difference(first, second, 'id_request', 'comment_bapak');
                console.log(diffs);
                alert(diffs[0].comment_bapak);
                refreshByManager();
            }
        });

    }, 5000);
}
```

So, in main document will be like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initializedFirstComment(function(output) {
        refreshByManager(output); // Check it
    })
}
```

I dont understand, why the output is like this :

```
    The result of debug :

console.log(diffs);
alert(diffs[0].comment_bapak); is =>

[]
TypeError: diffs[0] is undefined
```

I am so desperate. Any help it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tested the code a bit and the `difference` function returns an empty list if the `list2` doesn't contain objects that differ from the objects of the `list1`.
So I would check the `diffs` variable first, before trying to access it.

```
var diffs = difference(first, second, 'id_request', 'comment_bapak');
if (diffs) {
    console.log(diffs);
    alert(diffs[0].comment_babak);
}
```

Another problem I noticed is that you're defining the `difference` function over and over again in the `success` callback function. You should move it outside from there.